# Viewing Tokens on Ganache or an alternative

Tags: truffle, tokens, ganache

I'm currently working with the truffle suite and so am using ganache as my test blockchain. Is there something I can do with it or with a similar product to see token balances?

Comment: https://www.myetherwallet.com/  (list of networks, custom network)

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible within ganache but this will probably get implemented : https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/issues/94

You can use myetherwallet to see ERC-20 token balances but your node needs to be HTTPS or you have to run myetherwallet locally (which is available as a Chrome extension on the Chrome store and on github: https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet)

Answer (score 1):

You can use MetaMask to view the tokens you generated on Ganache.

To do this, you need to do the following:

1) Get the deployed contract address of your TokenContract in the folder 'builds/contracts > YourToken.json, and copy the **address** which you can find in networks: {}

2) Open MetaMask, link to your private network (in top of the MetaMask screen) and find the Add Token button (in the newest GUI, click the top-left menu icon and scroll down to see Add Token)

3) Click the 'Custom Token' tab

4) Copy your contract address in the 'Token Address'. MetaMask will automatically retrieve the other details if connected correctly. Click Next to add your custom token, and see your balance appear.

(if in Step 3 you didn't connect yet your private network to MetaMask, click in that top screen on the option 'Custom RPC' and fill in http://127.0.0.1:7545 (for Ganache) in the New Custom RPC Url field and click 'save').